# How do I read values from a text file and store them to be used in an equation in python

Tags: python, text-files

I have a text file that looks like the text below:

```
a,1234                        
b,34322      
c,9439   
d,132431
```

I want to write a code that reads just the numbers after the comma. For example, in the first line, only 1234 needs to be read by the code.

Then, that number(1234) needs to used in the equation *y = 10 + n*, where *n* is that number 1234. I want to read every number from every line and provide the result to me, and use those results for feeding into a chart, which also needs to be coded within the same program and saved as an image.

I have no clue how to approach this problem. All I did was type the following code, which reads those values from the text file and stores them in an array. I don't like that because that is just in one array. I seriously need help on this.

```
a1 = []

with open('project.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a1.append(line)
print (a1)
```

Comment: You can split the line on a comma then cast the number

Comment: Please do additional independent research. Focus on the `split()` string method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a1 = []

with open('project.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        before, sep, after = line.partition(',')        
        a1.append(after)
print (a1)
```

Comment: That does get rid of the everything before the comma and the commas. Now how do I use each of those values, input them in the formula, and display those results in a table?

Comment: Could you possibly help me with another question on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140621/read-and-add-the-last-value-from-an-array-pulled-from-a-text-file

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    a1 = []

```
with open('project.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        before, sep, after = line.partition(',')   
        n = after
        y = 10 + n
        a1.append(y)
print (a1)
```

Comment: actually it should be n = float(after) since the numbers are text.

Comment: You can edit your other answer instead of answering twice

Comment: Thanks. I just started answering a few questions on here yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
the pandas library is useful for dataset manupulations. The output is in a table format, which is now easier to plot.

```
import pandas as pd

#read file
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=",")

#do your calculation
data['y'] = 10 + data['n']
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> data
  Item       n       y
0    a    1234    1244
1    b   34322   34332
2    c    9439    9449
3    d  132431  132441

#do your plotting below...
```

Answer (score 0):

You started well. Your code:

```
a1 = []

with open('project.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a1.append(line)
print(a1)
```

Can evolve to `split` the lines and get only the second item (`[1]`):

```
a1 = []

with open('project.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a1.append(line.split(',')[1])
print(a1)
```

You can now cast it to number (considering they are integer):

```
a1 = []

with open('project.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a1.append(int(line.split(',')[1]))
print(a1)
```

Finally, it all can be a list comprehension:

```
with open('project.txt') as f:
    a1 = [int(line.split(',')[1]) for line in f]
print(a1)
```

I hope I’ve helped you. Any doubt, ask me.

Comment: What if I only want to display and store each number from that 2nd column, so that if anywhere in the code I want to add, subtract, multiply, divide, or whatever other function with that number, I can do. For ex: if I the first number 1234 to be added with 60 let's say, then I should just be able to say anywhere in the code; 60 + p, assuming 1234 is assigned to p.

Comment: I don’t know whether I understood you well… you want to store the retrieved value for future use in the same execution… is this? You can set `a1` to a module attribute or, preferred, you can pass it as parameter or return it from a function. So your `p` is one or each element of `a1`, like `a1[0]` or `for p in a1`.

Comment: The way I have my initial code, when I type in the following code, I get the 2nd column exactly as in the same format as in the text file, which is great on its own. `for p in t1:
    p+1;
    print(p)`

Comment: It's like all the numbers in that column are let's say four tennis balls. The problem is I will have to carry all those tennis ball together. I don't want that. I should be able to pick out any tennis ball I want and throw it wherever I want. Make sense?

Comment: I think I got it. I will post a reply if I have any trouble.

Comment: Could you possibly help me with another question on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140621/read-and-add-the-last-value-from-an-array-pulled-from-a-text-file