# Read and add the last value from an array pulled from a text file

Tags: python, equivalence

This is an example:
I have four time periods labeled as t=0, t=1, t=2, t=3. Each time has a value associated with it as shown below:

the format of the text file is as follows:
0,213
1,-999
2,456
3,-1100

Basically, each of the value is in one period.
What I want to do is to use those values and get all the values to t=0.
If I draw a timeline, then I would have two values on the positive at t=0 and t=2, and two values on the negative at t=1 and t=3.

Now, I want to go from the right hand side of the timeline to the left to get to t=0. So, at t=3, which is the last value in the timeline needs to move two units to the left to be added to the value of t=1 because they both are on the negative side, then finally move that value from t=1 to t=0. Similarly, I will need to do that for the positive side.

Following is my code. It may not be correct, but I am trying:

```
import numpy as np

workspace = 'C:\\Users\MM\Desktop'

time= np.loadtxt(workspace +'\\Assign1.txt', delimiter = ',', usecols = range(1))
value = np.loadtxt(workspace +'\\Assign1.txt', delimiter = ',', usecols = range(1,2))
for x in time:
    x+1;
    print(x)

for y in value:
    y+1
    print(y[-1])   
# I want this to read the last value(-1100) from the array
# of the text file I have. I already got the values 
# pulled from the text file. It gives me an error.
```

If I do get that to work, then since this is a negative value, I need to add that to the previous negative value, and so on.

The content I have is just a sample. There could be more or less than 4 time values, and the negative values and positive values could be anywhere on the timeline. The goal is to get the all the negative and positive values in t=0 and see if the negative values equals the positive values or not. The values needed to be considered equal if one of the values is greater by 1 but smaller than or equal to 15.

Comment: So...you need help sorting your values?

Comment: Could you please update your question with a [minimal, runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Thank you

Comment: It is part of the process because I need to add all the negative and all the positive values to each other. That addition needs to be done in order from right to left getting to t=0.

Comment: @cricket_007 I updated the code. It should run except you will need to make that text file. That last print statement doesn't because of `y[-1]`

Comment: @MasterMind I really don’t understand what you want. I read, and read again, but it makes no sense to me. Can you explain it other way? What did you mean by “move that value from t=1 to t=0”, for example.

Comment: @Arĥimedeςℳontegasppα Prune got it. If you like, then you can help me with my next question I have under his code.

Comment: @Arĥimedeςℳontegasppαℭacilhας Can you please help me with the question on the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797433/make-the-percentages-equal-using-a-formula-function-in-python-for-the-values-pul

Answer (score 0):

Algebraically, what you describe is much simpler than the process you've laid out.  You add up *all* the numbers and see whether the result is in the range [-15, 15].  Replace your two intended loops with this conditional check:

```
if -15 <= sum(value) <= 15:
    # Here, insert the code for matching stuff.
```

---

As for why your given code fails ... the loops are not correct.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the two **+1** expressions; they don't affect the data flow in any way, because you don't store the value.

The second loop is confused.  In each iteration, you take a single value from the list.  Your print statement treats that single value as if it were a list, too (you *can* make a list of lists in Python, but this program doesn't do that).  When you try to access the last element of a single integer, Python informs you of the confusion.

To print the last value of the list, simply use **print value[-1]**; don't iterate through the entire list to find the last item.

---

That said, we now have the original problem: how to sum the negative and positive values *using the algorithm you describe*.  You need to run your lists in the reverse order.  I'll do this in two loops, one each for positive and negative:

```
time = range(10)
value = [213, -999, 456, -1100, -16, 5, 42, -80, 9, 10]

last_neg = 0
for i in range(len(value)-1, -1, -1):   # Go through the list in reverse order
    if value[i] < 0:
        value[i] += last_neg
        last_neg = value[i]

last_pos = 0
for i in range(len(value)-1, -1, -1):   # Go through the list in reverse order
    if value[i] > 0:
        value[i] += last_pos
        last_pos = value[i]

print "pos & neg sums", value[0], value[1]
value[0] += value[1]

print "grand sum", value[0]

print "Check the summation:", value
```

Output:

```
pos & neg sums 735 -2195
grand sum -1460
Check the summation: [-1460, -2195, 522, -1196, -96, 66, 61, -80, 19, 10]
```

Comment: Thanks!! for that. I actually have a constant that I need to multiply before moving to the left, so if I were to move 10 to the left then assuming my constant is 2.5, the answer would be 10*2.5 + the next number, which as a whole becomes a new number. In our case, that would be 34. And, you do 34*2.5 + the next number. How do I do that ? I tried to do `value[i]*2.5 += last_neg`, but that is giving me an syntax error: can't assign to operator.

Comment: **value[i] += 2.5 * last_neg** ... note that you *really* need to work through some introductory programming exercises.  You *have* to learn how to write basic expressions and statements before you get into any sort of control structures (loops and functions) or data structures (lists, dictionaries, etc.).  Take a few hours so you don't have to keep asking for help on how to write a single math computation or list iteration.

Comment: I figured the problem I was having. I want to multiply the number by 2.5(constant) even if there is no positive or negative value as we move to the left. So, we have 10*2.5 + the next number, which is 34. Now, the next number is negative, so I want to do 34*2.5. Even if there is no positive number for "time", I need to always multiply the constant, and then move to the left. How do I do that?

Comment: Please see my earlier comment on learning the language basics.  SO is not a place to have someone else write your program, one or two lines at a time.  This is the third distinct question you've asked under one heading.

Comment: Can you please help with my question on the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797433/make-the-percentages-equal-using-a-formula-function-in-python-for-the-values-pul